# Quick way to split string at first sign of a digit

Tags: c++, string

I have a list of data I need to parse that contains a name and phone number in a text file. The name and phone number must be split into different string vars, but I can't really think of a fast method to do so. I can easily run a for loop and do something like

```
//file line read into string `line`
string name;
string number;
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
  if(isDigit(line[i])) {
    name = line.substr(0, i-1);
    number = line.substr(i, line.length()-i);
  }
}
```

but I feel there has to be an easy way to do this in C++.

Comment: You can speed this up by adding a `break` inside the `if`. This would also make it correct :-)

Comment: 1) Name can contain digit. For ex. "Richard 2nd" 2) Phone can start with sign "+". For ex. "+00123456789"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to find the first digit without using a loop:

```
string s("hello12345");
size_t i = s.find_first_of("0123456789");
string name(s.substr(0, i));
string number(s.substr(i));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0WbhNJ)

Note that if you wish to take a substring to the end of the original string, you do not need to pass the length: the library will figure it out automatically for you.